# Java Add Numbers In String

Tags: java, arrays, string, sum, substring

I'm creating an application which will take an image as input and use tesseract and give an output. This image has numbers (can vary the numbers)

I'm getting an output of, (when i run on the image)

```
0
1
12
1

0
```

I'm currently getting `5`which is `0+1+1+2+1+0` cause im removing the white spaces and adding them individually. I'm wondering is it possible to get `14` which is `0+1+12+1+0` and get the answer?

```
String a = result.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
for (Character eachNumber : a.toCharArray()) {
    totalMarks += Integer.parseInt(eachNumber.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have currently written.  Remove any unnecessary bits, however.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you show the code you're currently using; otherwise, people will assume you're just asking for others to write a program for you.

Comment: Absolutely possible. Tough to advise without knowing your code logic

Comment: "why is the code needed?" You asked if it's possible; as Trobbins replied, it absolutely is. Just about anything is _possible_ with Java. Without showing us your code, you're essentuially asking us "give me code that does this", which is not a service we provide. When we can see your code, we can tell you what's wrong with it and explain what you need to change to get it to work. Easier on us, more beneficial for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't remove the whitespaces, you should split according to them:

```
int sum = 0;
String[] parts = output.split("\\s+");

for (String part : parts) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(part);
}
```

Comment: it should be `String part : parts`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
String[] lines = data.split("\\r?\\n");
```